# return code of individual script ,though they are running in parallel

Tags: shell-script, parallelism, exit-status

I have jar file which is running in parallel with multiple table names as arguments using `nohup` command in unix

```
nohup java -jar batchorch.jar $tablename &
```

I have used below lines for getting status wrt to all jar files

```
oldpid=$!
wait $oldpid
echo $?
```

How can I get status of each `jar` file individually though they are running in parallel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not aware of a method to handle the background processes in the order in which they finish.

```
#!/bin/bash
  
declare -a bg_pids

ec=0

(sleep 10; exit "$ec") &
bg_pids+=($!)
((ec++))

(sleep 10; exit "$ec") &
bg_pids+=($!)
((ec++))

(sleep 10; exit "$ec") &
bg_pids+=($!)
((ec++))

for pid in "${bg_pids[@]}"; do
    echo -n "PID ${pid}: "
    wait -f "$pid"
    echo $?
done
```

Output:

```
PID 29807: 0
PID 29808: 1
PID 29810: 2
```

Answer (score 0):

With GNU Parallel the information is available in `--joblog`:

```
nohup parallel --joblog my.log java -jar batchorch.jar {} ::: table1 table2 table3
```

The relevant column is Exitval:

```
Seq     Host    Starttime       JobRuntime      Send    Receive Exitval Signal  Command
1       :       1597644202.601       0.003      0       0       1       0       java -jar batchorch.jar table1
2       :       1597644202.604       0.008      0       0       1       0       java -jar batchorch.jar table2
3       :       1597644202.613       0.005      0       0       1       0       java -jar batchorch.jar table3
```